# Using python regex to exclude '.' at the end but not inside a string

Tags: python, html, regex

I am trying to use python regex to spot `@mentions` such as `@user` and `@user.name`

So far I have:

```
htmlcontent = re.sub(r'((\@)([\w\.-]+))', r"a href='/users/\3'>\1 /a>", htmlcontent)
```

When this code spots a `@mention` ending in a `.` it does not exclude it:

e.g.  Hi `@user.name.` How are you?

Output so far:

**`<a href='/users/user.name.'>@user.name. /a>`**

Desired output:

**`<a href='/users/user.name'>@user.name /a>`** <-- without `.` after `name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
re.sub(r'((\@)([\w.-]+[\w]+))', r"<a href='/users/\3'>\1</a>", htmlcontent)
```

this will let the re engine know that '.' and '-' can be in the middle - but the string must end on a character.
running on your example:

```
In [3]: htmlcontent = 'Hi @user.name. How are you?'
In [4]: re.sub(r'((\@)([\w.-]+[\w]+))', r"<a href='/users/\3'>\1</a>", htmlcontent)
Out[4]: "Hi <a href='/users/user.name'>@user.name</a>. How are you?"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a positive look ahead for the `.` at the end of the match like

```
([\w\.-]+)(?=\.\s)?
```

**Example**

```
string = "Hi @user.name. How are you?"
print re.sub(r'@([\w\.-]+)(?=\.\s)?', r"a href='/users/\1'>\1 /a>", string)
#Output
#Hi a href='/users/user.name.'>user.name. /a> How are you?

string = "Hi @user.name How are you?"
print re.sub(r'@([\w\.-]+)(?=\.\s)?', r"a href='/users/\1'>\1 /a>", string)
#Output
#Hi a href='/users/user.name'>user.name /a> How are you?
```